# Observing change in UIDatePicker

Tags: objective-c, ios, uidatepicker, key-value-observing

I noticed that there is no delegate to observe changes in UIDatePicker. Is there a way to detect when a change is made in the picker without confirming anything, like the moment it spins and lands on a new number I want to be able to detect that. I thought about key value observing, but I don't think there's a property that changes on the spot

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Go to IB and drag from the `UIDatePicker` to your .h file. Then select[image]

Handle this however you want in your .m file; XCode will add the method below for you.

[image]

Comment: Of course its the easiest solution I didn't even consider. Thanks man

Answer (score 70):

You need to add to your UIDatePicker the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event to handle date changes:

```
[myDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateIsChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then the implementation:

```
- (void)dateIsChanged:(id)sender{
     NSLog(@"Date changed");
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I'm too lazy for this programmatic stuff. Note that you'd need a reference to the date picker to do this, which you wouldn't necessarily have if you created it in IB (although you could easily add it).

Comment: Swift version:

`picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

@objc func dateChanged(sender: UIDatePicker)  {
    print(sender.date.description)
}`

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4.2  |  Xcode 10.1**

```
@objc func handleDatePicker(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    textField.text = datePicker.date.formatted
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
        return formatter
    }()
    var formatted: String {
        return Date.formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal for a KVO-compliant date picker:

```
@interface LNKVODatePicker : UIDatePicker

@end

@implementation LNKVODatePicker

- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow
{
    [super willMoveToWindow:newWindow];

    [self removeTarget:self action:@selector(_didChangeDate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    if(newWindow != nil)
    {
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(_didChangeDate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeTarget:self action:@selector(_didChangeDate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)_didChangeDate
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"date"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"date"];
}

@end
```